# error when create GCMIntenetService class

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

I followed this topic http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html#libs  to create GCM I did all steps well but when I am going on create class GCMIntenetService  I had more errors on the class some of errors "cannot be resolved to type" , "return type of the method missing ..." ... please if any one help.

package com.example.elarabygroup;

public class GCMIntenetService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

```
private static final String LOG_TAG = "GetAClue::GCMIntentService";

public GCMIntentService() {
    super( GCM_SENDER_ID );
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    Log.i( LOG_TAG, "GCMIntentService constructor called" );
}

@Override
protected void onError( Context arg0, String errorId ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i( LOG_TAG, "GCMIntentService onError called: " + errorId );
}

@Override
protected void onMessage( Context arg0, Intent intent ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i( LOG_TAG, "GCMIntentService onMessage called" );
    Log.i( LOG_TAG, "Message is: " + intent.getStringExtra( "message" ) );
}

@Override
protected void onRegistered( Context arg0, String registrationId ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i( LOG_TAG, "GCMIntentService onRegistered called" );
    Log.i( LOG_TAG, "Registration id is: " + registrationId );
}

@Override
protected void onUnregistered( Context arg0, String registrationId ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i( LOG_TAG, "GCMIntentService onUnregistered called" );
    Log.i( LOG_TAG, "Registration id is: " + registrationId );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks I had solved my problems as I didnot add any namespaces:

```
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
```